# Extract phone numbers from multiple org files

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

I create one folder per person for my patients. For every visit a new org file is created in a folder with date stamp.org as file name. The org file contains name and phone number of the person in addition to other details. I would like to extract name and phone numbers to a single file. Is it possible. Kindly help.

Comment: Do you have a specific format / template for names and phone numbers, or are they entered as free text?

Comment: Name , date of birth, phone number, current date in consecutive lines wrapped in flush right environment